# Adding Context to A Tricky Jquery Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a Jquery function that looks for certain `<div>` elements and inserts information into them. I have two identical containers with 10 blank `<div>` elements inside each. When I click to run my function it loads information correctly into the first set of blank `<div>` elements. When I click to run the function again on the second container it loads the content back into the first one again.

I've been researching context in Jquery and I believe this *might* be my solution. The way I assumed it would work is that I would tell my function "only run in this specific container", so that it would work successfully in both containers.

**Live Example:**
1. Click "Images". Reddit will load correctly.
2. Click "BuildaPCSales. Loads information back into Images instead.

https://brotherhoodgaming.net/reddit.php

**Script**

```
function loadRedditData(redditSearch) {
    $.getJSON(
        'https://www.reddit.com/r/' + encodeURIComponent(redditSearch) + '.json',
        function foo(data) {
            $.each(
                // iterate over 10 children, starting at the 0th index
                data.data.children.slice(0, 11),
                function (i, post) {
                    //Load reddit title in correct div//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditTitle').append(
                        $('<a>')
                            .attr('href', 'https://m.reddit.com' + post.data.permalink)
                            .text(post.data.title)
                    );

                    //Load reddit Score (net UP - DOWN)//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditScore').prepend(
                        $('<p>')
                            .attr('class', 'redditUpvoteScore')
                            .text(post.data.score)
                    );

                    //Load reddit post-text in HTML format//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditPost').append(
                        $('<p>')
                            .text(post.data.selftext_html)
                    );

                    //Load sub-reddit name in HTML format//
                    /*$('#news' + i + ' .subRedditName').append(
                     $('<p>')
                     .attr('class', 'subRedditFormat')
                     .text('r/' + post.data.subreddit)
                     );*/

                    //Load post thumbnail URL into an <a> tag wrapping the image//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditThumbnail').append(
                        $('<a>')
                            .attr('href', post.data.url)
                            .attr('class', 'thumbURL')
                    );

                    //Load actual thumbnail into the <a> wrapper tag with the thumbURL class//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .thumbURL').append(
                        $('<img>')
                            .attr('src', post.data.thumbnail)
                            .attr('class', "image news hide floatleft")
                    );

                    //Load reddit Username and URL into container DIV//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .userNameContainer').append(
                        $('<a>')
                            .attr('class', 'redditUserName')
                            .attr('href', 'https://m.reddit.com/user/' + post.data.author)
                            .text(post.data.author)
                    );

                    // Convert post creation time to local time//
                    var utcSeconds = post.data.created_utc;
                    var d = new Date(0);
                    // The 0 is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
                    d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);

                    //Use Moment.js to calculate relative date and append to DIV//
                    $('#news' + i + ' .redditDate').append(
                        moment(d).fromNow()
                    );

                    //Decodes HTML into correct format by replacing unescaped characters//
                    $('.redditPost').each(function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var t = $this.text();
                        $this.html(t.replace('&lt', '<').replace('&gt', '>'));
                        $this.html(t.replace('null', '').replace('null', ''));
                    });

                    //Checks for "self" tagged images and replaces with placeholder image//
                    function changeSourceAll() {
                        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
                        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                            if (images[i].src.indexOf('self') !== -1) {
                                images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("self", "css/images/default.jpg");
                            }
                        }
                        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                            if (images[i].src.indexOf('default') !== -1) {
                                images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("self", "css/images/default.jpg");
                            }
                        }
                        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                            if (images[i].src.indexOf('https://www.brotherhoodgaming.net/default') !== -1) {
                                images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("https://www.brotherhoodgaming.net/default", "css/images/default.jpg");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    changeSourceAll();
                }
            )
        }
    ).error(function () {
        alert("We are unable to locate your desired subreddit OR you have requested a subreddit that does not exist.");
    })
}
```

**HTML structure**

```
<div class="redditContainer">
        <div class="redditHeader">
            <p class="subRedditTitle">Images</p>
            <i class="material-icons redditHeaderCollapse">
                arrow_drop_down
            </i>
        </div>
        <div class="cardbox news nopad" style="display:none;">

            // There are 9 more identical copies of these.
           // Removed to save space

            <div class="listrow news nomargin">
                <div class="newsContainer">
                    <div class="redditThumbnail clearfix floatleft"></div>
                    <div class="articleHeader read clearfix">
                        <div class="actionmenuHeader">
                            <div class="userNameContainer"></div>
                            <div class="redditFlair"></div>
                            <div class="subRedditName"></div>
                            <div class="redditDate"></div>
                            <div class="redditScore">
                                <i class="redditUpvote material-icons">
                                    keyboard_arrow_up
                                </i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="redditTitle clearfix mediaTitle news"></p>
                        <div class="redditPost mediumtext"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to load correctly into each container individually? I have rearranged my function multiple times over the last 5-6 hours and I'm getting no closer to solving my problem.

Comment: How are you activating the `loadRedditData()` function?

Comment: Currently I have a "one("click" ....) setup for each redditHeader. When you click on any header it takes the text value and passes that as a variable (subreddit) into Loadredditdata and then calls the function. I'll post the code when I get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your live example, there are divs with id `newsx` where x is 1-20. Since with `$.each`, the index `i` will always start at 0. So only the first 10 `newsx` divs will be updated everytime.

You should preferably be passing on the element like:

```
$('.redditHeader').one("click", function() {
    var redditSearch = $(this).children('.subRedditTitle').text();
    loadRedditData(redditSearch, this);
});
```

And then capture it in the loadRedditData function by adding a parameter

```
function loadRedditData(redditSearch, element){
    //code
}
```

Then based on the element variable in loadRedditData you can use:

```
var newsList = $(element).next().children();
```

This will contain the list of all the `newsx` divs(this might be incorrect if the DOM is changed) under the current header. Currently the DOM returns all the `newsx` divs that are under the selected header. You can then use the array index on `newsList[i]` to access each one of the `newsx` divs. For example:

```
$(newsList[i]).find('.redditScore');
```

Also you are currently looping through 11 records and using all records except the first one. Doing it the way I showed above would use only the first 10 records and skip the last one.

Comment: Hi @DVJex, you had me up until the var newList portion. Where does that get inserted inside loadRedditData? Would that be placed just before the $.getJSON call?

Comment: Also you are correct, I am currently passing the element exactly as you have written above. Thanks again for taking a look at this!

Comment: @DavidWashburn It can be anywhere before it's first use. Preferably before the loop so that the code doesn't get executed multiple times.

Comment: Ah I see it's a variable, not sure how I missed that. I've checked my code against yours, however the only thing missing was adding the word "element" to my "loadRedditData(redditSearch, element)", and inserting that newsList variable. Unfortunately it still seems to be loading into the top div only.

Comment: I expanded my answer a bit. Also I think you're missing something. Are you using `$(newsList[i]).find(className)` where className are the classes you're using like redditScore and redditTitle?